# How to align margin-top; with css

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, margins

I have a site that looks kind of like this:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/94786808/Example1.png

You'll notice the title "Post Production" is correctly aligned horizontally, but not vertically. When I try to align it vertically using the "margin top" command in css, this happens: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/94786808/example2.png

You can see that the title is now in the correct place, but the "box" containing it has moved as well. Here is the css involved:

Container (to hold it in place)

```
.container {
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     background-color:#FFF;
     width: 960px;
     height: 609px;
}
```

---

Post Production (the gradient box)

```
.postproduction {
     width: 960px;
     height: 203px;
     background-image:url(../image/departments/bg.png);
     opacity: 0.5;
     -o-transition:.2s;
     -ms-transition:.2s;
     -moz-transition:.2s;
     -webkit-transition:.2s;
}
```

---

and finally, Titlepost (the physical text)

```
    .TitlePost {
          margin-top: 101px;
          margin-left: 35px;
          font-family: 'NeouBold';
          font-size: 30px;
```

}

---

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: try `padding-top` instead of `margin-top` in `.TitlePost` or try `vertical-align: center`

Comment: As long as `.TitlePost` is within `.postproduction` it shouldn't cause what you're seeing...

Comment: Try setting `position: relative` for `.TitlePost`.

Comment: really? https://dl.dropbox.com/u/94786808/Example3.png

Comment: Aram fixed it :) Switch margin to padding :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code would probably be better structured like this:

### Html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="postproduction">
        <p>Post Production</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Css

```
.container {
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     background-color:#FFF;
     width: 960px;
     height: 609px;
}
.postproduction {
     width: 960px;
     height: 203px;
     background-image:url(../image/departments/bg.png);
     opacity: 0.5;
     -o-transition:.2s;
     -ms-transition:.2s;
     -moz-transition:.2s;
     -webkit-transition:.2s;
}
.postproduction p{
          padding-top: 101px;
          padding-left: 35px;
          font-family: 'NeouBold';
          font-size: 30px;
}
```